# 'address already in use ' exception throws in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl

Tags: jvm, gemfire

I try to run a *.sh file in linux system ,this *.sh file is used to start a Java Application.this Application use gemfire as its distributed cache system. it seems that i can not build a new tcp connection of gemfire. is there anyone knows how to solve this problem?

here is the exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl.<init>(AcceptorImpl.java:378)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BridgeServerImpl.start(BridgeServerImpl.java:297)
        at spark.cache.CacheServicePoint.enableServer(CacheServicePoint.java:197)
        at orion.di.service.profile.ProfileService.initialize(ProfileService.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
```

Answer (score 0):

Address already in use is that already your application instance is running/listening on the same port. If you are an ubuntu user

```
netstat -tulpn | grep YOURAPPNAME
```

This will give you the ProcessId which is running the instance in your system. Find the process Id number and kill the instance and start the application once again. 
To kill

```
kill -9 PROCESSID
```

Comment: `kill -9` should be used only if standard kill fails. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process

Comment: one more question,in this command 'netstat -tulpn | grep YOURAPPNAME' .how do i put the APPNAME. i know it's about gemfire,should i put 'gemfire' to fullfill this command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting two processes of your Java application on the same box? GemFire server by default opens up a port on 40404 to listen to client connections, so when you start more than two servers on the same box, the second one gets an `Address already in use` exception. Look the script used to start your application. You will need to provide a different port for each GemFire server you are trying to start. Using GemFireShell i.e. `gfsh` this could be done like so:

```
 gfsh>start server --name=server1 --server-port=4045
```

Or, if there are no clients (i.e. peer-to-peer deployment of GemFire), you can disable listening to clients like so:

```
gfsh>start server --name=server1 --disable-default-server
```